# Why did mounting /media/MMMCSD work?

Tags: mount

I am novice Ubuntu user. I've struggled mounting my SD card on my Ubuntu 11.04. However, I've googled the issue and now I'm able to mount the card. But, I don't know what difference the command made that enabled the SD card to mount and usable? Please help!!

Here is the command I've used to change the settings.

```
sudo mkdir /media/MMCSD
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

then deleted the line starting with /dev/sdb1

then replaced it with the command below

```
/dev/hdb1 /media/MMCSD vfat auto,user,sync,exec,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=007 0 0
```

This did the magic. Please explain.

Answer (score 4):

Which bit don't you understand?

1. `sudo mkdir /media/MMCSD` created a directory for you to mount the SD card to. Mounts require a "mount point", this is yours.
2. `sudo nano /etc/fstab` this edits `/etc/fstab` as root.
3. `/dev/hdb1 /media/MMCSD vfat auto,user,sync,exec,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=007 0 0` is the mount command. When the system boots, it looks for the device `/dev/hdb1` and mounts it at your new mount point. It sets the filesystem to vfat (a fairly typical filesystem for a SD as well as setting a number of fairly default options to allow you to use the drive from your user account.

Answer (score 2):

On top of Oli's excellent answer:

`fstab` stands for `file system table`. It is a configuration file that tells the operating system what *disk partition* the Os needs to *mount*, as well as the *mount point* in your file tree. You can also mount/unmount paritions dynamically (see `man mount`).

The line you added to the file tells the the OS to mount the partition `/dev/hdb1` at the mount point `/media/MMCSD` (your first step made sure the directory existed). The other options are fairly default, as mentioned.